# Python - How to use adapter interfaces

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write in OOP for the first time using python. It still doesn't feel right passing the interface type through the main controller. I'm trying to follow the SOLID principles. Let me show the code.

TicTacToeOnConsol.py:

```
import os
from Controller import StartController

os.system('cls')
StartController().StartGame('consolInterface')
```

Controller.py:

```
from UserInterface import ExecuteActionOnInterface

class StartController:
    def StartGame(self, strInterfaceType):
        dispWelcomeContinue = ExecuteActionOnInterface().DisplayWelcome(strInterfaceType)
        if dispWelcomeContinue == False:
            return False
        #Do more stuff
        return True
```

UserInterface.py:

```
from ConsolInterface import ConsolInputMessages
from ConsolInterface import ConsolOutputMessages

class ExecuteActionOnInterface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.selectDisplayWelcome = {
            'consolInterface' : ConsolInterface().DisplayWelcomeConsol,
            'windowInterface' : WindowInterface().DisplayWelcomeWindow,
            'webInterface' : WebInterface().DisplayWelcomeWeb,
        }
    def DisplayWelcome(self, strInterfaceType):
        self.selectDisplayWelcome[strInterfaceType]()
        return True

class ConsolInterface:
    def DisplayWelcomeConsol(self):
        return ConsolInputMessages().DisplayWelcomeWithInput()

class WindowInterface:
    def DisplayWelcomeWindow(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('This interface has not yet been implemented')

class WebInterface:
    def DisplayWelcomeWeb(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('This interface has not yet been implemented')
```

ConsolInterface.py:

```
import os
import msvcrt as inputKey

class ConsolInputMessages:
    def ContinueOrQuit(self):
        print "Any Key = Continue"
        print "Q = Quit"
        print "Please press Any Key to continue, or Q to quit:"
        continueOrQuit = inputKey.getche().upper()
        if continueOrQuit == 'Q':
            print '\n'
            print '\nExiting Game...'
            return 'quit'
        os.system('cls')
        return 'continue'

    def ContinueRestartOrQuit(self):
        print "Any Key = Continue"
        print "Q = Quit"
        print "R = Restart"
        print "Please press Any Key to continue, R to restart, or Q to quit:"
        continueRestartOrQuit = inputKey.getche().upper()
        if continueRestartOrQuit == 'Q':
            print '\n'
            print '\nExiting Game...'
            return 'quit'
        elif continueRestartOrQuit == 'R':
            print '\n'
            print '\nRestating Game...'
            return 'restart'
        os.system('cls')
        return 'continue'

    def DisplayWelcomeWithInput(self):
        ConsolOutputMessages().DisplayWelcome()
        if self.ContinueOrQuit() == 'quit':
            return False
        return True


class ConsolOutputMessages:
    def DisplayWelcome(self):
        print """\
******************************************************
**************** Welcome to TicTacToe ****************
******************************************************
Copyright (c) 2014 fiddlefreak
All Rights Reserved

This product is protected by copyright and distributed under
licenses restricting copying, distribution and decompilation.
"""
```

Any python experts who can give me some examples of how the UserInterface can instantiate the Consol Interface as it's own object, so when the controller calls a function on the interface, it doesn't have to pass through the type, and the UserInterface already knows which one to use?

Comment: Don't put answers in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass a string value of the interface type, pass an instance of the class (or, pass the string, and have the controller instantiate the interface). You can do this when you create the controller. Save the reference to the interface, then directly call methods on that interface:

```
interface = ConsoleInterface()
StartController(interface).StartGame()
...
class StartController:
    def __init__(self, interface):
        self.interface = interface

    def StartGame(self, interface):
        self.interface.DisplayWelcome()
        return True
```

Comment: Thanks, I was seeing similar syntax with the init through google. I just wasn't sure about how to implement it by passing a class instance. You're awesome :)

Comment: I also updated the main question for easy review (to help the next guy).